Spring Rabbit Test - Requeue on AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException Not Working
I’m trying to execute a test using Spring Boot with the 'spring-rabbit-test' dependency. My application flow involves a calls a service, which processes messages in parallel using RabbitMQ queues. In my code, I have a sender and a listener. The listener includes logic for retrying by throwing the exception AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException.
However, when I run the test and this exception is thrown, the code stops, and my test only completes when the "waiting" period finishes. I don't fully understand how this should work and why my retry control isn’t functioning as expected. Extra datail! When I use TestContainer with RabbitMQ, the test works normally.
Service:
package io.springrabbittest.example.service;

import io.springrabbittest.example.integration.EksSyncClient;
import io.springrabbittest.example.model.DataMock;
import io.springrabbittest.example.queue.SyncSender;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j2;
import org.springframework.amqp.AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.List;

@Log4j2
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SyncTaskDataService {

    private final SyncSender syncSender;
    private final EksSyncClient eksSyncClient;

    public void startDataSyncTaskInitial(final List<DataMock> data) {
        data.parallelStream().forEach(syncSender::sendDataToSave);
    }

    public void saveData(final DataMock dataMock, final Long retry) {
        try {
            log.info("-->> Enter on the save!!!");
            eksSyncClient.sendToEks("", dataMock);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.info("-->> Error on save data {}", dataMock);
            if (retry <= 3) {
                log.info("-->> {} Throw AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException {}", retry, dataMock);
                throw new AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException(e);
            }
            log.info("-->> Pass the control!!!");
            eksSyncClient.sendToFailEks("", dataMock);
        }
        log.info("<<-- OUT!!!");
    }

}


Test:
package io.springrabbittest.example.service;

import io.springrabbittest.example.SyncApplicationTest;
import io.springrabbittest.example.integration.EksSyncClient;
import io.springrabbittest.example.model.DataMock;
import io.springrabbittest.example.queue.SyncSender;
import io.springrabbittest.example.util.MockUtils;
import org.awaitility.Awaitility;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.test.TestRabbitTemplate;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;


class SyncTaskDataServiceTest extends SyncApplicationTest {

    @Configuration
    static class TestConfig {

        @Autowired
        private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

        @Bean
        public SyncTaskDataService syncTaskDataService(final TestRabbitTemplate testRabbitTemplate,
                                                       final EksSyncClient eksSyncClient) {

            final SyncSender syncSender =  new SyncSender(testRabbitTemplate);

            return new SyncTaskDataService(syncSender, eksSyncClient);
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    private SyncTaskDataService syncTaskDataService;

    @MockBean
    private EksSyncClient eksSyncClient;


    @Test
    void shouldExecuteSuccessWhenAdminTriggerActionSyncData() {
        final List<DataMock> data = MockUtils.generateData(100);

        doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(eksSyncClient).sendToEks(any(), any());

        syncTaskDataService.startDataSyncTaskInitial(data);

        Awaitility.await()
            .atMost(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .pollInterval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .untilAsserted(() -> {
                verify(eksSyncClient, times(400)).sendToEks(any(), any());
                verify(eksSyncClient, times(100)).sendToFailEks(any(), any());
            });
    }

}

